# No Musicians for a Schochet

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, music, employment, slaughter-shochet-shecht

I was told that the Aruch Hashulchan says that a Musicians may not be a Schochet does anyone know where it says this and if it is true and why that is?

Comment: Where did you hear such a thing?

Answer (score 6):

[Aruch HaShulchan Hilchos Shechita 1:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14242&st=&pgnum=7) says that one who is too involved in Chochmas Hanegina will not pay proper attention to the Halachos of Shechita

Comment: Nice find.........

Comment: anyone any ideas why musician versus others? like why not say you cant have secondary jobs as you will be "too involved"?